# Fabric Js Multiple Canvas or Rerendering same canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am working on fabric js project where I want user to be able to work on front and back side. Up till now we were using one canvas and then saving the json whenever a user switched sides. We would then re-render the json onto the canvas. We also save canvas image at this point in time.

Now,I am thinking of using two canvases and hiding one when the user switches sides. No re-rendering and saving image until user saves his work. It would be easier to manage the code this way, I am just not sure if it would be better performance wise as well?

Comment: Since FabricJS serializes the entire canvas it would make common sense to create 2 FabricJS canvases of you have front & back components to your app.

Comment: Yup. Did that. Obvious performance changes. Thanks

Comment: don't think this is a good idea according the memory. Each pixel of canvas will cost 4 bytes so more canvases definitely more memory cost. And also fabric have all kinds of cache for objects you created on it, each object you create on the canvas which is visible also have one cache object in a canvas that is invisible. This also cost a lot of memory. Maybe just test your solutions on safari 12 for now(because safari 12 sometimes has a memory leak issue with fabric js) to see if everything works properly, especially when you have many objects there.